# How to convert Java enum to Swift enum?

Tags: java, ios, swift, enums, migrate

Below is my java enum.
I want to convert it to Swift enum.
Can you please help me to migrate?

```
package com.lifeplus.Pojo.Enum;

public enum GattServiceEnum {
 
    CURR_TIME_SERVICE("00001805-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "current_time"),
    DEVICE_INFORMATION_SERVICE("0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "device_information"),
    PULSE_OXY_SERVICE("00001822-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "pulse_oximeter"),
    CUSTOM_SERVICE("4C505732-5F43-5553-544F-4D5F53525600", "Custom Service");

    private final String _id;
    private final String _desc;

    GattServiceEnum(String pId, String pDesc) {
        _id = pId;
        _desc = pDesc;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return _id;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return _desc;
    }
}
```

Plaese help me to convert this to Java.

Comment: You asked a similar question recently and it got closed...

Comment: Yes, But I can't get the proper solution.

Comment: That is not a reason to re-post the question. Edit your original question please.

Comment: Original question is deleted.

Comment: Why is this an enum and not a struct?

Comment: You did not ask an answerable question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use an `enum`.  You can simply use a `struct`

```
public struct GattService {

    public let id: String
    public let desc: String

    // You can optionally provide the get functions, but it is simpler just to access the properties directly

    public func getId() -> String {
        return id
    }

    public func getDesc() -> String {
        return desc
    }
}
```

Comment: BATTERY_SERVICE("0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "battery_service"),
    BP_SERVICE("00001810-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "blood_pressure"); I have this type of cases too. What I do?

Comment: Well, you could make static members of `GattService` like `static let batteryService = GattService("0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "battery_service")` or you could use associated types with an enum but rather than blindly porting code from some other language and platform you should implement the equivalent for *this* platform.  e.g. Core Bluetooth defines `CBUUID` and already supports 16 bit well-known GATT identifiers.  You really need to edit your question to explain your real problem, not just "how do I do this Java thing in Swift?"

Answer (score 0):

try this، Hopefully it will be useful for you:

```
public enum GattServiceEnum {
    
    case myNameCase(id: String, desc: String)
    case anotherCase
    case onlyIdCase(id: String)
    case onlyDescCase(desc: String)
    
    public func getId() -> String? {
        switch self {
        case .myNameCase(let id, _),
             .onlyIdCase(let id):
            return id
            
        case .anotherCase, .onlyDescCase:
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    public func getDesc() -> String? {
        switch self {
        case .myNameCase(_, let desc),
             .onlyDescCase(let desc):
            return desc
            
        case .anotherCase, .onlyIdCase:
            return nil
        }
    }
}

// create
let myEnumObject = GattServiceEnum.myNameCase(id: "123", desc: "hi")

// get id
print(myEnumObject.getId())

// get desc
print(myEnumObject.getDesc())
```